# Help explicit formula for a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

what would the explicit formula be for the sequence 0, -1/2, 2/3, -3/4, 4/5, -5/6, 6/7?

I am having trouble locating a similar pattern between each term.

Comment: $$
\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, every other term is negative. We can take a sequence of positive numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ and make it alternate negative and positive like this by multiplying $(-1)^n$. That is, we get $(-1)^0 a_0, (-1)^1 a_1, (-1)^2 a_2, (-1)^3 a_3, \ldots$.

So, we just need to find a formula for $0, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, \ldots$. Hopefully, that shouldn't be an issue: just take $a_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$. So, the general form for the sequence is,
$$a_n = (-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1}.$$